# Pygame: How can I make a sprite always move to the right?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

I want my sprite (a 2d top down fighter plane) to always move to the sprites'a right. I currently have it so the plane rotates to where the mouse pointer is.  Now I need the plane to always be moving and so you can rotate it with your mouse while the plane is flying. A short code example would be excellent as I am not very experienced.  The sprite is "plane.png". I am using Python 2.7 if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few things you may want to clarify before you start implementing anything. First, do you actually want the sprite to move in relation to the *window*, or do you want the sprite to stay stationary and have the background scroll, giving the player the impression that the sprite is moving across your game's landscape?

Assuming you want the sprite itself to move, you'd want to create a method within the sprite's object that constantly updates it's x position to a slightly higher number

```
while True:
    xpos += 1
    display_image = pygame.image.load(plane.png)
    display.blit(display_image, [xpos, ypos])
```

The above snippet while increment the x position of your sprite by 1 every frame. If you haven't already set a limit to the number of frames rendered per second, I'd suggest taking a look at [creating a clock in pygame and calling the tick function every time the game loop runs](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

Alternatively, you could do the same as above, but pass in the mouse cursor's current coordinates to have the sprite follow your cursor.

If you'd rather have the sprite stay stationary and move the background, you could do the same thing for each element of your background, just in reverse.

```
while True:
    xpos -= 1
    display_image = pygame.image.load(background.png)
    display.blit(display_image, [xpos, ypos]
```

Hope this is helpful!